# CS0019 Cannot multiply Vector2 and double

Tags: c#, godot

I am using C# and Godot.

I have been able to multiple Vector2 and float but the movement of the character does not work when delta is a float.

direction is a Vector2 and both speed and delta are double.

Here is my code:

```
Velocity = direction.Normalized() * speed * delta;
```

The line of code results in CS0019 error stating that operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector2' and 'double'.

I am unable to change speed and delta into a float because if delta is a float, `_PhysicsProcess` cannot be overridden and does not move the character:

```
public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
```

Answer (score 5):

Documentation does not list [`Vector2` multiplication operator](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#operator-descriptions) accepting `double`. Try using `float`s (via casting):

```
Velocity = direction.Normalized() * (float)(speed * delta);
```

Or just declare `speed` and `delta` as floats from the start.

Note that his cast is not lossless (i.e. not every double can be correctly converted to float).

See also:

- [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)
- [Operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: I'd probably cast to `float` after the multiplication so as to not lose precision unnecessarily: `(float)(speed * delta)`.